# No stringWithContentsofURL method found

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm following [this tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2009/06/18/objective-c-20-an-intro-part-1/), attempting to learn a bit about iPhone development, and there come a point where the author uses the stringWithContentsofURL method but xcode is telling me that there is no stringWithContentsofURL method found.  I've done some searching and I've not been able to come up with a solution.  This is a screen shot of the xcode window displaying the error:
[alt text http://mywebprogrammer.com/so/obj-c%20problem%200.png](http://mywebprogrammer.com/so/obj-c%20problem%200.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringWithContentsofURL:` is a class method, not an instance method, so you have to use it as

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL]
```

or if you want to allocate it yourself, you would do:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL]
```

but then you would have to release it later

Answer (score 1):

Its [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL]. Note: its the capital 'O' (in Of) not small 'o' as given by you. Also Its a static method so cannot be used against an object.

Comment: Nitpick: It's a class method. Objective-C does not have static methods. They generally serve a similar purpose, but they're not quite the same.